# Neo4J introducing a relationship variable affects results in a multiple-hop relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Taking my first steps in Neo4J - there's something I don't quite get (perhaps related to syntax)

Why does this returns results

`MATCH (d:People)-[HAS_VEHICLE*]->(v:Vehicle) return d,  v`

while this doesn't return any results

`MATCH (d:People)-[r:HAS_VEHICLE*]->(v:Vehicle) return d,  v`

The difference between them is the introduction of the relationship variable - but why would it affect whether the query returns results or no results at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the difference between the 2 queries is that the first query does not specify a *relationship type*. Instead, the first query specifies `HAS_VEHICLE` as an *identifier*.

Relationship types must be preceded by a colon. So, your first query should have been:

```
MATCH (d:People)-[:HAS_VEHICLE*]->(v:Vehicle) return d, v
```

[EDITED]

The above query should also return no results, which means that there are no paths in your DB that match the pattern specified. For example, to match the above pattern, all relationships have to be of the `HAS_VEHICLE` type.

You can modify the query to not require the `HAS_VEHICLE` type, and to return the actual relationship types along the paths that match the resulting new pattern:

```
MATCH (d:People)-[rels*]->(v:Vehicle)
RETURN d, EXTRACT(r IN rels | TYPE(r)) AS types, v;
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. So now I'm getting no results. Does this mean the adjusted above query isn't designed to retrieve vehicles that are 2 hops away from People `(people)->(films)->(vehicles)`?

Comment: No, it means that there are no paths in your DB that match the pattern specified. For example, to match the above pattern, all relationships have to be of the `HAS_VEHICLE` type. I will add more info to my answer.